# Always open a window when the Combox selection is the last item

Tags: c#, wpf

As shown my ComboBox has total three items.

If I click the last item that means the item3, then a window will appear that's fine.

But my requirement is I want to click the item3 again and the window should open again without clicking any other tabitem in this case tab item1, item2.
How can I do this? Can this be achieved?

xaml:

```
<ComboBox Name="cb2" Width="400" Height="30" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"  SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedIndex="{Binding Selected}">
           
        </ComboBox>
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ViewModel vm;
       
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            vm = new ViewModel();
            DataContext = vm;
           
        }
       
    }
    public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            List = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
            List.Add(new Model() { Name = "itme1" });
            List.Add(new Model() { Name = "itme2" });
            List.Add(new Model() { Name = "itme3" });
           
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Model> List { get; set; }
       
    private int _selected;
    public int Selected
    {
        get
        {
            return _selected;
        }
        set
        {
            _selected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Selected");
            Window1 win1 = new Window1();


            if (_selected == List.Count - 1)
            {

                win1.Show();

               
            }
            else
            {
                win1.Close();
            }

        }
    }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        internal void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        } 

       
    }
    public class Model
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

the result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRaL9.gif)

**Update:**

```
private void cb2_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Window1 win1 = new Window1();


            if (vm.Selected == cb2.Items.Count)
            {

                win1.Show();


            }
            else
            {
                win1.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use the `SelectionChanged` event, because otherwise your ViewModel cannot "see" the user action that does not change any bound property value

Comment: You may want to look at listening to the `PreviewMouseDown` and `PreviewMouseUp` events. Once the item is selected, clicking it again will not reselect the item to fire the event again.

Comment: Hi，@StefanWuebbe. When the same Item is clicked again, will the SelectionChanged method be executed? Where should the code to open and display Window1 be written so that it can be executed when the same Item is clicked again?

Comment: Hi,@FelixCastor. I tried the PreviewMouseDown event, the code is in the update of the question. When Item3 is clicked for the first time, after the window Window1 is opened, Item3 is clicked again, but a new Window is not opened. I want to open a new Window1 every time I click on Item3.what should I do？